# type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool

Tags: solidity

[This part of the code creating an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCpOe.png)

I am trying to run a function which return the index number of the coing if match complete. but when i run this function it seem to be creating an error. The main problem is in for loop i is a unit variable for index to check the newcoin list with the finder.

```
     // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract BasicFunction 
{
string coinName = "Epic Coin";
uint public myBalance = 100;

struct Coin
{
    string name;
    string symbol;
    uint supply;
}
mapping(address=>Coin) internal myCoin;
// function(unit _variable1, string _variable2) public view/pure return{bool};
function getGuess(uint _guess) public pure returns (bool) {
    if(_guess == 5)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
// only be call by externaly like use
function multiplyBalance(uint _multipier) external {
 myBalance = myBalance * _multipier;
}
// function with array
function findcoinIndex(string[] memory  _mycoin, string memory  find, uint _findForm) public pure returns(uint)
{
    
    for(uint i = _findForm; _mycoin.length; i++)
    {
        string memory  newcoin = _mycoin[i];
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(newcoin)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(find)))
        {
            return i;
            
        }

    }
    return 999;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for your for loop.

```
for(uint i = _findForm; _mycoin.length; i++)

should be

for(uint i = _findForm; i < _mycoin.length; i++)
```